# Map not adding an array of overlays

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I've an overlay array of `MKPolyline` objects and an array of annotations to be added on a map view. The annotations are being added but the overlays are not added on to the map view.

**My code for addition of those overlays and annotation goes as -**

```
-(void) addOverlay:(TropicalStorm *)storm{
//tropicalStorm is my model class for storing an overlay array and annotation array


    NSArray *overlay = storm.overlays;
    NSArray *annnotations = storm.annotations;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.mapView addOverlays: overlay];
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];

    });




    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKOverlay> overlay in storm.overlays) {
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
            flyTo = [overlay boundingMapRect];
        } else {
            flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, [overlay boundingMapRect]);
        }
    }
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [MapUtilities regionForAnnotations:storm.annotations];
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:region.center zoomLevel:6 animated:YES];

}
```

What might be the issue in this code or why is it not being rendered ?

Comment: Did map view fully render itself?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Ya I am adding other details along with the annotations which are successfully being added except this one.

Comment: what is the use of flyTo ? Where are you using it ?